# Action bar and menus not shown in AccountAuthenticatorActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-authenticator

Since I use an action bar instead of menus for my application, no action bar nor/ menus are shown in my implementation of AccountAuthenticatorActivity. Other activities show action bar without problem.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or a missing adaptation of the code on my side. Has someone experienced the same problem? I didn't find any other question related to this problem.

```
public class MyAuthenticatorActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {
```

...

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }
```

XML menu that should be right as it is used in many other activities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuHome"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:orderInCategory="110"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/menu_home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="111"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuInfo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info"
        android:orderInCategory="113"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/menu_info"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is late. But I was able to get around this base on this [one](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3). It seems the `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` doesn't really have an `ActionBar` for some reason. Esp. it is really hard to work on when you want to use the support-library.

Here is how I did it:

You have to enclose your activity layout using a `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout_homescreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_login"
    tools:context="com....LoginActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbarlayout_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        ...
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see, I placed an `AppBarLayout` as per the docs and have the `appcompat` version of the `Toolbar`  here. We will assign this `Toolbar` later.

If you prefer to make the `CoordinatorLayout` just like any ordinary activity without animated-coordinated scroll, you can just set the attribute of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` like the following:

```
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

This will make sure your `Toolbar` will not disappear/collapse when you scroll up as the minHeight has been set to `?android:attr/actionBarSize`. You can checkout its behavior [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout).

Next on your `LoginActivity` which extends `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`, you have to use `AppCompatDelegate` but before that make sure you LoginActivity implements the `AppCompatCallback`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity
        implements AppCompatCallback
{
    ...
    private AppCompatDelegate mAppCompatDelegate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        ...
        mAppCompatDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);
        mAppCompatDelegate.setSupportActionBar(mToolbarLogin);

        ActionBar actionBar = mAppCompatDelegate.getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.activity_login));
        mCollapsingToolbarLayoutLogin.setTitleEnabled(false);
    }
```

There are three methods you have to implement, but on my research they seem to do nothing fancy esp if you only want to show an `ActionBar`, so on this use-case you can leave them blank:

```
@Override
public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
{

}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode)
{

}

@Nullable
@Override
public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback)
{
    return null;
}
```

The line `mAppCompatDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);` ask for the `Activity` instance on the first param, the second param is asking for the callback.

Also, another thing. If you want the back button to be present as shown on this code, it doesn't respond to click. You may have to override it:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
```

One small quirk I found going using this is that the status bar appeared white on some devices. I am still looking how to fix it but at least the `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` now has an `ActionBar`. I don't like this solution as it is a little bit hacky to may taste. So much hassle to implement a seemingly basic behavior for `Activity`.

HTH